# GAE - Writing permission on files

Tags: google-app-engine

I've deployed a PHP CodeIgniter application on an App Engine and there are two files that need write permission.

Can't find a How-to to help with setting those permissions. Any help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/runtime#the_sandbox) A PHP App Engine application cannot:

write to the filesystem. PHP applications can use Google Cloud Storage for storing persistent files. Reading from the filesystem is allowed, and all application files uploaded with the application are available.

You might use [flex](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/the-appengine-environments#comparing_high-level_features) to write to ephemeral (disk initialized on each VM startup)

Edit:
You can find the php storage client libraries [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-php), the idea is instead writing files locally, write them and access them from Google Cloud Storage

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but not sure I understood...I am very limited on gcloud...is there a how to document or post on how to fix that? Thank you!

Comment: Yes, I edited my answer to include de php libraries for cloud storage which you can use instead of writing to local storage